# Detect number and wrap specific function?

Tags: php

We have functions to format telephone numbers, I am looking to create an if statement to switch which functions to use..

Here are 2 example phone numbers:

`1300123456
0412345678`

If the number begins with 04, we want to wrap the string inside `formatMob()`

If the number begins with 1300, we want to wrap the string inside `formatLocal()`

Whats the best way to do a detect on these numbers?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'd personally put the logic inside of the formatter function, and just have one, rather than two separate ones, but if that's how you want it:

```
$num = 123123123;

if( substr($num, 0, 2) == '04' )
{
  // call first function
}
elseif( substr($num, 0, 4) == '1300' )
{
  // call other function
}
```